# Python - find all regex

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of fake ids in a text file. I wanted to capture all IDs that starts with 'A0015'. I tried different regex but they are not capturing the final output. Which regex should be using?

```
text = "Here are the fake student ids: IDs A0015-4737, IDs: A0015-384721-ADA2ad, A0015WE382 \n A00152838. Please enter this."
capture_id_list = (re.findall(r"A0015 ([\w-]+)", text,flags=re.IGNORECASE))
print(capture_id_list) # results with []
# print(text.startswith('A0015')) # Gives False...not usefull

find_this = "A0015"
capture_id_list = text[:text.find(find_this) + len(find_this)]
print(capture_id_list) # Here are the fake student ids: IDs A0015. Not the results
```

Final Output:

```
['A0015-4737','A0015-384721-ADA2ad','A0015WE382','A00152838']
```

Comment: Your regex has a space in it that the patterns don't.

Comment: you can toy with your regex at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `r"(A0015[^ ,.]+)"` in  your code:

```
>>>import re
>>>text = "Here are the fake student ids: IDs A0015-4737, IDs: A0015-384721-ADA2ad, A0015WE382 \n A00152838. Please enter this."
>>>capture_id_list = (re.findall(r"(A0015[^ ,.]+)", text,flags=re.IGNORECASE))
>>>print(capture_id_list)
['A0015-4737', 'A0015-384721-ADA2ad', 'A0015WE382', 'A00152838']
```

Here () is a capture group. It catches a string beginning with A0015 and one or more characters (the + sign) that differs from space, comma or dot (characters in the [] braces negated by ^ sign].

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you: `r"(A0015[^\s,.]*)"`, inline it would look like this:

```
capture_id_list = (re.findall(r"(A0015[^\s,.]*)", text,flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

`(A0015[^\s,.]*)`

- 1st Capturing Group `(A0015[^\s,.]*)`

  - `A0015` matches the characters `A0015` literally (case insensitive)
  - **Match a single character not present in the list below**: `[^\s,.]*`

    - `*` **Quantifier** — Matches between **zero** and **unlimited** times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
    - `,.` matches a single character in the list `,.` (case insensitive)